# Adding text to html textarea

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="main">
<textarea rows ="20" cols="80" name ="output_box" id ="output"></textarea>
</div>
```

What I want it to do is to add text to that area on a button click like so

```
<div class="classname"  button type =onclick="myFunction()" >
    Export
</div>
```

and this is what it calls

```
<script>
    function myFunction()
     {
         var obj = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
         var text = document.createTextNode("Test data");
         obj.innerHTML = text;
     }
</script>
```

But after much frustration I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Hint: in your code, `obj` is a string.

Comment: Your variable is `txt` and youre trying to append variable `text`

Comment: I'm sure that would be relative, but I still have no idea.

Comment: I corrected txt to text and still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with the changes below: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/hZw6q/

Your JS should be closer to this:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("output");
var txt = "Test data";
obj.value = txt;
```

1. `txt` != `text`
2. As Matt Ball pointed out, "`obj` is a string," not an object.
3. You don't need `document.createTextNode` as you're using `value` instead of `innerHtml`

Your HTML should also be:

```
<div class="classname" type="button" onClick="myFunction()">
    Export
</div>
```

And not:

```
<div class="classname"  button type =onclick="myFunction()" >
    Export
</div>
```

Comment: I changed the HTML.  But I still cannot get it to function properly via the javascript.  It just says object data.

Comment: What error code are you getting?

Comment: It just says [object Text] in the field.

Comment: Updated. Since you're not using `innerHtml` and instead using `value`, you don't need `document.createTextNode`. Also, I changed the function so that it would play nicely with jsFiddle.

Comment: Yeah, I changed it to obj.appendChild(text); and that worked.  Your's is functional as well.  I thank you for your direction.